# How to know Wi-Fi signal strength in dBm?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

In Windows, Wi-Fi link speed (in Mbps) can be found in the Wireless Network Connection Status dialog:

[image: Connection Status screenshot]

But how can I find out the Wi-Fi signal strength in dBm? There are several Android apps that can measure signal in dBm. Is there any way to it in Windows? Because the bar graph Wi-Fi icon for Wi-Fi in Windows is not clear enough to predict signal strength properly.

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/794327/windows-7-collect-wireless-signal-strength-via-command-line - and YES there are plenty of 3rd party tools which can do this. Basically all wifi scanners for windows I have ever encountered do show you the dB value